# Android Custom EditText text alignment bottom

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-edittext, vertical-alignment

I created a custom drawable for the background of an EditText. I  need the text to be left and bottom aligned. It renders fine on screen but the text is not aligned to the right nor the bottom of the drawable. I also tried gravity:bottom and tried setting the padding on top in hopes it would move it down. Is there anything else I can do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right and bottom lines define the content area.

The line you draw on the right spans the top half of your image. That's why the text won't align to the bottom.

You should draw a slightly longer line.

Check out the image used by default. (I changed it to blue here though).

[image]

This will give the same result you are having. The text won't be aligned to the bottom.

Now if I extend the right line to the bottom, I would obtain the below image.

[image]

This will give you the expected result.

Comment: Ah I see. So if the right line defines the vertical alignment, then does the bottom line define the horizontal alignment?...i.e: if I wanted to left align the text, would I extend the bottom line to the left?

Comment: This is not working for me. I copied your example image directly.  The bottom of the text is still a considerable distance away from the bottom line. Now, I did try moving the bottom line of the edit text up and it was then right underneath the text but then there is too much padding between the bottom of the editText and the view below it. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I figured out what the issue was..once I set all the selector states to the same drawable like in Benito's example above, then the text in the custom editText was aligned correcly